# Why differential equation reduces?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to ND-Solve the following equation:

```
eqns = {x''[t] == -x[t], x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 4}
```

The problem, is when I enter it, Mathematica reduces it to

```
{x''[t] == -x[t], True, x[0] == 4}
```

And because of that NDSolve fails.

The Mathematica basic help page on the NDSolve error was not very useful, because x and x[0] were not defined prior to the equation.

My questions are:

- Why is the reduction happening?
- How I prevent it from happening and solve my differential equation?
- How could I figure in the future where from the following problem arises?

Comment: Restart the kernel and try again.

Comment: ...or run `Remove[x]` and try again.

Comment: `Remove[x]` worked, but not `ClearAll["Global\`*"]`. Why x was not accessible through the globals but was accessed by `Remove`?

Comment: Check `FullForm[x'[0]]` to see why `Clear[x]` won't have an effect if you have inadvertantly set `x'[0]=0`.

Comment: `Derivative[1][x][0]`. I guess it is stored than in the `Derivative[1]` namespace rather than globals?

Comment: Correct.  I have marked this question as a duplicate as I feel that it may be useful this way.  If you object I can revert the change and closed as "a simple mistake" (as it was previously) it will be deleted in time.

Comment: I think duplicate could be a good option to improve visibility for people searching for same error.